# Should I save length of object before looping through object?

Tags: java

Is it better coding practice to pre-compute and save the length of an array before looping through the object?  Similarly, what about for strings?

```
//Given int Array A, that won't change size
for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++)
     System.out.println(A[i]);
```

vs

```
int Asize = A.length;
for (int i = 0; i < Asize; i++)
    System.out.println(A[i]);
```

--
similarly for strings

```
//Given string s, that won't change size
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    System.out.println(s.charAt(i));
```

vs

```
//Given string s, that won't change size
int sSize = s.length();
for (int i = 0; i < sSize; i++)
    System.out.println(s.charAt(i));
```

Comment: The difference, if any, is vanishingly small.

Comment: Thanks.  Is the same true for strings?

Comment: The following is always true: *Don't worry about performance, worry about writing readable code. That doesn't mean to write wildly inefficient code; but don't worry about minutiae. When you find code is too slow, profile it; only when you find that this is the most important bottleneck in your code should you try alternatives.*